# How to invoke a method with in the controller and from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got stuck with this scenario. Let me explain as follows. I have a movies model, for a movie a user can give a rating and he can comment for a movie. So I have points table. Based up on the number of comments, rating and average rating e.t.c I wrote a method def points end in my movies controller.

I have a comment controller and method in it separately for creating a comments, and for rating a movie I have written a a method in my movies controller for creating ratings. Hope Im clear till now.

so my problem statement is. I want call this points method in movies controller at the time of creation of ratings and comments.

for brief insight Im pasting my code here.

In movies controller my two methods(ratings and points)

```
 def rate

    @movie= Movie.find(params[:movie_id])

    @count=0

     @test= Rating.find(:last, :conditions=>['movie_id=?', @movie.id])

     unless @test.nil? || @test.blank?

     @count= @test.count


     end

         if(params[:submitted])

            if @movie.ratings.create(:movie_id => params[:movie_id], :rate => params[:rating], :user_id=> current_user.id, :count=> @count+1) 

              points    

              flash[:success] = "Rating was successfully saved."  

            else

              flash[:error] = 'Error. Rating was not saved. Try again later.'

            end

            redirect_to @movie

          end


end

 def points

  @user= current_user

  @movie= Movie.find(params[:movie_id])

  total_comments_by_user=Comment.find(:all, :conditions=>['user_id=? AND movie_id=?',@user.id,@movie.id]).count

  user_who_rated= Rating.find(:all, :conditions=>['user_id=? AND movie_id=?',@user.id,@movie.id])

    @user_who_rated.each do |ur|

      if @user=ur.user_id

        @ratings_of_each_user=ur.rate

     end 

       end


     @over_all_comments_of_movie=Comment.find(:all, :conditions=> ['movie_id=?', @movie.id]).count


 @records=Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ['movie_id=?',@movie.id]).collect(& :rate)

    unless @records.nil? || @records.blank?

      @average_rating = 0.0

        @records.each do |r|

          @average_rating += r

       end 

     @average_rating = @average_rating/@records.size

 end


   unless @ratings_of_each_user.nil? || @ratings_of_each_user.blank?

    if @total_comments_by_user.nil? || @total_comments_by_user.blank?

     else

   @div_one=@ratings_of_each_user*@total_comments_by_user

    @div_two=@over_all_comments_of_movie* @average_rating

      @total=0.0

      @total=@div_one.to_f/@div_two.to_f


 @find_user_in_points= Point.find(:all, :conditions=> ['user_id=? AND movie_id=?',current_user.id,@movie.id])

  if @find_user_in_points.nil? || @find_user_in_points.blank?

   Point.create(:user_id=> current_user.id, :movie_id=>@movie.id, :points=> @total)

     else

       @find_user_in_points.each do |f|

        if f.user_id= current_user.id

          f. update_attributes(:points=> @total)

        end

     end

      end

      end

    end

  end
```

Now comments controller

```
def create

   @user=current_user

    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])

     @select_params= params[:choice_list] || []

     if @select_params.nil? || @select_params.blank?

       @comment = @movie.comments.create(params[:comment])        


      @comment.update_attributes(:user_id=>@user.id, :commenter => @user.username)

     else

   @comment= @movie.comments.create( :commenter => "user", :body=>params[:comment][:body] , :movie_id=> @movie.id, :user_id=>@user )

      end

    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end

 def destroy

    @comment = Comment.find(:all, :conditions=>['id=?',params[:id]])
    @comment.delete
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end
```

I have rate movie link on my view file and a form to add a comment to the movie. I just want to invoke that points method when ever a rating is created and comments are created so that i can perform my points caluculation internally and update my points table.

Guide me please. Is it possible to call a method in one controller from the other controller if so how and tell me how to call a method in the same controller.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a shared method that you can call from both controllers?  You really shouldn't be calling Controller A from Controller B... controller methods are for browser requests only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call another controller. If you need to share method, either make sure its in the model (if that's the correct place for it) or in a shared controller like ApplicationController

Also...
`unless @test.nil? || @test.blank?` - `String#blank?` checks .nil? first. So the .nil? is not necessary.